# How do I work with a C++ program containing non-Latin characters?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program that was written by a Russian-speaking developer and so it contains Cyrillic characters. When I open the sources they are displayed as garbage. How do I solve this in windows ?

Comment: aren't they written in c++ first of all? what's in russian language there?

Comment: means they have not written the code in english... its shows different characters cant understand one line of the program written in c++

Comment: @ramu_mzz: Maybe it will be more efficient if you roll in some very short snippet illustrating the problem.

Comment: ð¾åè« its showing in this way... just asked how to convert the files to english

Comment: The language the identifiers are named in does not matter to C++. So your question is how do I translate Russian to Englisch and that's an easy question. Since the identifiers are probably not cyrillic and the transciption to latin letters is probably not used in any dictionary you could use for automatic translation, I guess your best chance is to find someone who speaks both and does it for you for a reasonable price.

Comment: I hope you're aware that the letters in your example are not cyrillic ("russian")... so my guess would be, your first problem is either on of encoding or - and I really don't hope so - you opened a binary file...

Comment: I've edited the question - were my edits right?

Comment: Great, I'll then upvote your question since it's a typical problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem is your IDE/editor doesn't display Cyrillic characters correctly. You solve this by changing the IDE/editor settings to use a font that contains Cyrillic characters - for example, Courier New if you're on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Well, assuming they've actually used ISO C and not some weird Russian variant, the language constructs and standard library calls will be in English (or its strange cousin, American).

The only thing you'll really need to convert are the strings (such as for user output or logging), code comments and variable names.

And even the comments and variable names may not *have* to change. They may make the code harder to understand to a non-Russian reader however.

If the code contains characters that your current editor doesn't understand, well, you need to get yourself an editor that does. Or get your Russian friends to turn it into English for you.

Comment: There're almost probably no weird local variants around here, I can assure you. The compilers are standard and comments are in Broken English. :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that there is another C++ programming language in russia. So you just need to replace the strings to the other language, i.e. English. Care must be taken when processing input since here you can find handling of single characters.

A better approach would be to prepare a localization. You can read all strings from a ressource or file. In that case you can select the resource that matches you target language.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the strings of the program are written in Russian and you want to add English texts, you need to first internationalize (i18n) your program, using instead of static strings a library like [Gettext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_gettext); then you need to add support for the English locale.

If you mean that the variables and the comments are in Russian and you want them in English, well.. find a translator ;)

Answer (score 0):

Find a translator and give him the code.